# kubernetes nginx ingress concurrent connections

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rate-limiting) link, the **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections** annotation sets the number of concurrent connections allowed from a single IP address. Is there a way I can sets the number of concurrent connections allowed in total?

Comment: Why do you want to set number of concurrent connections allowed? If you are running out of resources you should scale up, and once no longer needed scale down.

Comment: It is a business requirement to limit the connection.

Comment: I think you would need to setup something in front of the k8s to set that limit. For example a firewall or maybe proxy?

Comment: what you want is nginx upstream max_conns  limits. It's not supported by kubernetes/ingress-nginx yet. but it's supported by nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress, check `nginx.org/max-conns` in https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe are mistaking the concepts. This annotation is specific for handling with multiple connections with one client. It has security purpose (mitigate DDoS attacks).

As [@Crou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156333/crou) said, if you are receiving a large amount of connections, you could scale up. Or else, if you want to limit the connections to this service, you should define settings to not scale. But, you can run a out of service issue eventually.

Comment: It is a business requirement to limit the connection